# How to erase a variable set in universal scope in fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

I had set GOROOT as an universal varaible with the command

`set -x -U GOROOT /usr/local/go`

Which is now causing problems and i want it unset, I did try to erase with `set -e GOROOT` and several other things, but that only erased for that specific shell session if I started a new session it was still there, could someone help me with this, Im relatively new to Fish.

Output of `set --show GOROOT` is:

```
$GOROOT: set in global scope, exported, with 1 elements
$GOROOT[1]: |/usr/local/go/bin/go|
```

Comment: right now i have found a workaround by adding the `set -e GOROOT` to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Answer (score 2):

`set -e` will erase the variable in the lowest scope.

Since this variable is both universal and exported, you also inherit a global *copy* from the parent process, and global scope is below universal scope.

So you need to either erase it *twice* (once for global, once for universal), or explicitly specify the scope:

```
set -e -U GOROOT
```

Comment: hi thanks, i actually tried this before it had returned with a non-zero status.

I'll try it again

Comment: Update: I tried  both `set -e -U GOROOT`[failed] `set -e -g GOROOT`[ successful], but it only erased the variable for that session

Comment: In that case the parent process is most likely still exporting that variable from its global copy. You probably need to reboot your system or log out and log back in, depending on which process still holds a copy.